# move object until another key is pressed

Tags: python, tkinter

So I am trying to design the game of snake without using the pygame or turtle libraries and I have encountered a problem regarding making a rectangle move. I have tried a bunch of ways to get the object to move continuously until outside input is given, with no luck. Below is a recent attempt.

```
import tkinter as tk

# Main Window
window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("700x700")


# Creating snake body
canvas = tk.Canvas(window, width=700, height=700)
canvas.pack()
bod1 = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 25, 25, fill='red')


# Moving the snake
def move_snek(event):
    x = 0
    direction = event.char
    xdot, ydot = 0, 0
    while x <100:
        if event.char == "a":
            xdot = -.1
        elif direction == "d":
            xdot = .1
        elif event.char == "w":
            ydot = -.1
        elif event.char == "s":
            ydot = .1
        canvas.move(bod1, xdot, ydot)
        x+=1

window.bind("<Key>", move_snek)
window.mainloop()
```

When the code is in the while loop, it does not seem to be doing the canvas.move but does do the x+=1 line below it

Comment: @martineau Thanks for the tip. I edited it to be a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does work. It just happens too fast that it is hard to see.

I suggest the use of `.after()` method to keep moving your rectangle until a new key is encountered. You can make use of `.after_cancel` to remove the scheduled job if a new key is pressed.

For what you are trying to achieve you also need to store your keypress and compare it with the new one. If it matches keep moving else stop.

Assuming you want your rectangle to keep moving in the direction of the key press. I have made a small example.

```
import tkinter as tk

# Main Window
window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("700x700")


# Creating snake body
canvas = tk.Canvas(window, width=700, height=700)
canvas.pack()
bod1 = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 25, 25, fill='red')


previous_key = None
after_id = None

movements = {"a": (-0.1, 0), "d": (0.1, 0), "w": (0, -0.1), "s": (0, 0.1)}


def move_snake():
    global after_id

    if previous_key not in movements.keys():
        if after_id:
            canvas.after_cancel(after_id)
            after_id = None

    else:
        canvas.move(bod1, *movements[previous_key])
        after_id = canvas.after(50, move_snake)


def key_press(event):
    global previous_key
    
    previous_key = event.char
    move_snake()


window.bind("<Key>", key_press)
window.mainloop()
```

The above program stops only when a non-wasd key is pressed.

Comment: Thank you. That helped a lot

Comment: For some reason the rectangle seems to be accelerating after each button press

Comment: @AlexD add this `if event.char == previous_key:  return` in `key_press` function before `previous_key=event.char`, and tell me if that works.

Comment: I tried that method and the acceleration still seems to occur

Comment: @AlexD where did you add that line? Can you paste your code in [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) and paste the link in the comments?

Comment: Certainly. https://pastebin.com/FjWAPGTB  One way to easily experience this acceleration would be to quickly hit the "a" and "d" keys. Pressing any key outside the 4 movement keys resets the speed.

Comment: @AlexD try [this](https://pastebin.com/JK3FZNp1) and tell me if this works for you.

Comment: Thank you, that worked. What is the functionality of after_id? It seems to speed up the box when I change the delay of 50 milliseconds to 5 milliseconds.

Comment: @AlexD think of `widget.after(ms, fun)` like a countdown timer, the function reference that you pass in after will be called after every 5 milliseconds in your case. It is not the `after_id` that's speeding up your box, it's the time that you passed into the `after` method, increase the time, to slow down the call. `after_id` is the id returned by the `after` method which can later be used to cancel a scheduled timer.

Answer (score 0):

Your question's a little vague about what interrupts the movement, so here's another solution that keeps it going as long as one of the movement keys is being pressed and stops when it's released. It does the by binding the `'<KeyPress>'` and `'<KeyRelease>'` events  to separate functions which a global movement vector.

There's a third function named `move_snek()` which checks this movement vector and uses it to update the position of the rectangle in the direction specified by its current value.

The way it's run periodically is by using the [`after()`](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/universal.html) universal widget method to schedule calls to it after a specified delay in milliseconds.

```
import tkinter as tk

SPEED = 5  # Updates per second.
DELAY = 1000 // SPEED  # Milliseconds between updates.

# Main Window
window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry('700x700')


canvas = tk.Canvas(window, width=700, height=700)
canvas.pack()

# Creating snake body
bod1 = canvas.create_rectangle(325, 325, 375, 375, fill='red')

move_vector = None
vectors = {'a': (-1, 0), 'd': (1, 0),  'w': (0, -1), 's': (0, 1)}

def keypress(event):
    global move_vector
    move_vector = vectors.get(event.char, None)
    move_snek()

def keyrelease(event):
    global move_vector
    if event.char in vectors:
        move_vector = None

def move_snek():
    if move_vector:
        canvas.move(bod1, *move_vector)
    canvas.after(DELAY, move_snek)


window.bind('<KeyPress>', keypress)
window.bind('<KeyRelease>', keyrelease)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you for the help